# How to copy an existing hbase table

Tags: hadoop, cloud, hbase

I have a Hbase table X and I want to create an exact copy of it and name it Y. Could someone let me know how it is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 36):

Assuming you want to copy the table on the same cluster you can use HBase snapshots
in the `hbase shell` you can

```
snapshot 'sourceTable', 'sourceTable-snapshot'
clone_snapshot 'sourceTable-snapshot', 'newTable'
```

Comment: Prior to version 0.94.6, the only way to backup or to clone a table is to use CopyTable/ExportTable

Comment: How can we clone a table in 0.94.1? As I learnt, snapshot is available in the newer versions

Comment: Beware this bug requiring superuser permissions to clone tables if using server <1.4.0:  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-16724

Answer (score 7):

CopyTable command is very handy to replicate HBase Tables. Use it in the following way:

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.CopyTable --new.name=Y X;
```

Comment: I tried this one but I want it to cross replicate on a different cluster's table

Comment: it says "undefined local variable or method `new'". What is it so?

Comment: does this method takes the exact copy? my table has readonly='false' in its description. I am creating a new table with the same fields as my table. But copying does not make its description as same

Answer (score 3):

use hbase shell
1. make sure you enbale snapshot in hbase-site.xml

```
  <property>
     <name>hbase.snapshot.enabled</name>
     <value>true</value>
    </property>
```

2. hbase> snapshot 'x' ,'snapshot_x' 
3. hbase> clone_snapshot 'snapshot_x' ,'another_x'

Answer (score 1):

In hbase shell check version;

```
hbase(main):001:0> version
0.90.4, r1150278, Sun Jul 24 15:53:29 PDT 2011
```

if older version of 0.94.6 then you should use mapredeuce jobs.
snapshots are available since 0.94.6
if it is above, you may use [toby941 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910323/how-to-copy-an-existing-hbase-table/20985829#20985829)
or you can use one of these

A)

```
./hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.CopyTable
Usage: CopyTable [--rs.class=CLASS] [--rs.impl=IMPL] [--starttime=X] [--endtime=Y] [--new.name=NEW] [--peer.adr=ADR] <tablename>
```

B-1)

```
./hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export
Usage: Export [-D <property=value>]* <tablename> <outputdir> [<versions> [<starttime> [<endtime>]]]
```

B-2)
then import with whatever name you want

```
./hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import
Usage: Import <tablename> <inputdir>
```

Comment: I tried this one but I want it to cross replicate on a different cluster's table

Answer (score 0):

According to the HBase documentations here ([1](http://hbase.apache.org/book/ops_mgt.html#copytable), [2](http://hbase.apache.org/book/mapreduce.example.html#mapreduce.example.readwrite)) are the options.

Answer (score 0):

this will work..

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export tableA /hbase_export/tableA

hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import /hbase_export/tableA tableAcopy
```

Comment: You have to create tableAcopy first. So, no, it doesn't work.

Comment: Your syntax is also incorrect, the import should be: bin/hbase -Dhbase.import.version=0.94 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import <tablename> <inputdir>

Answer (score 0):

Snapshot methodology may not work if you are on older version of hbase
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-8742
. In that case you may have to manually copy hbase schema and then apply snapshot or better to upgrade to fixed version.